# Is there a way in the API to find the nearest point placemark loaded thru a KML file from a given point on GE plugin?

Tags: google-earth-plugin

Is there a way in the Google Earth Plugin API to find and highlight the nearest point placemark from a given point(lat,long) on GE plugin? The KML file with few point placemarks is loaded to GE plugin through javascript code uging network link.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way to do this kind of query using the API, and in fact, NetworkLinks are intentionally made to be opaque to the API (for instance they don't show up in the KML DOM).

In the past, libraries built on top of the Earth API have worked around this by emulating NetworkLink functionality in Javascript, loading the KML via [fetchKml](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/google_earth_namespace#afca518f43d5f863b254c5fa23a5967f2) or loading via XHR and then into the plugin via [parseKml](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/interface_g_e_plugin#acd35e260277fb0ffb86b5b2a962551da). At that point you can select all the placemarks either by parsing the locations yourself (if you loaded the KML by XHR), or you can use [getElementsByType](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/interface_g_e_plugin#afb721b781531e181ce1be47feb6f3411)('KmlPlacemark') and then (finally) use a normal algorithm to find which is closest and highlight it in some way.